# set timezone to the local time of the client

Tags: php, mysql

I loaded my php script on hosting provider "byethost.com". I am trying to set the time of the records in the created_at to the local time of the client but I am always getting the GTM time. How can I get it to work?

```
 <?php
 $data = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( 'php://input', true ) );

$mac = $data->{'mac'};
$latitude = $data->{'latitude'};
$longitude = $data->{'longitude'};
$route =   $data->{'route'};

$timeZone = "Europe/Berlin";
$print = date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);

$con = new mysqli ( "domin.com", "username", "password", "database" );


// check whether route's table exist.
$results = $con->query ( "SHOW TABLES like 'bus' " ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {$sql = "REPLACE INTO bus(mac, route, latitude, longitude, created_at)
          VALUES( ?, ?, ? , ?, ? )";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

  if(false === $stmt){
    echo "prepare()  failed: ";
  }

  $rc = $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$mac,$route, $latitude,$longitude, $print);
 echo $rc;
  if ( false===$rc ) {
  echo "bind_param() failed: ";
}

  $rc = $stmt->execute();

  if ( false===$rc ) {
 echo "execute failed.";
  }

  $stmt->close();

} else {
  $create =  "CREATE TABLE bus
       (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        route int(11) ,
     latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL , 
     longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
     created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL" ;
   $stmt = $con->prepare($create) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();

}
```

Comment: You probably want to store all time in the DB in GMT and display time in the user's time zone.  See the answer from @fijiaaron in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792066/convert-utc-dates-to-local-time-in-php.

Comment: @steve: No I want to store the data (for testing purpose ) in the bus table in client timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with this?

```
date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);
```

Time zone can be something like:

```
"Europe/Oslo"
```

For the complete list of supported time zones see http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: I did it as you said and I am getting the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 ` This one is line 7. `created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL`? I updated my code please take a look.

Comment: To be honest I do not see how can date_default_timezone_set() cause a SQL error? O.o

Can you try putting this on top of your code (lines 6 and 7 to lines 2 and 3) and see if it still says line 7?